# How to obtain a collection of great grandparent records from a collection of child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is the problem:

- I have a collection of records which are: receipts. I want to obtain a unique list of projects which are associated with these receipt objects, in an efficient manner. I couldn't find a similar question/solution on SO for this particular type of problem.

This is what I want:

```
@projects = @receipts.getUniqueProjects()
```

```
# Project.rb

  has_many :conversations

# Conversation.rb

  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :project

# Message.rb

  has_many :receipts
  belongs_to :conversation

# Receipt.rb

  belongs_to :message
```

Is it possible?

The following looks promising: but how then do I access the grand parent records? Without iterating through the child records and incurring huge database overheads?

`Receipt.joins(message: [conversation: :project])`

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

### Here's what I used:

```
@projects = Project.joins(conversations: {messages: :receipts} ).where(receipts: [1,2,3,4]).uniq
```

Thank you Vasilisa - appreciate the foresight to see that this was an XY problem.

Comment: Happy to help :) Note, there is a difference between `uniq` and `distinct`. The first one finds uniq objects in resulting AR Relation and converts it to array, it means, that you can't use any AR methods after `uniq`. But the second one uses `SELECT DISTINCT` on sql level and works faster, because it selects only uniq objects, also it still returns AR Relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `has_many :through` association, it is useful for setting up "shortcuts" through nested `has_many` associations.

```
# Project.rb

  has_many :conversations
  has_many :messages, through: :conversations
  has_many :receipts, through: :messages

# Conversation.rb

  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :project

# Message.rb

  has_many :receipts
  belongs_to :conversation

# Receipt.rb

  belongs_to :message
```

In this case you can join them easily and use `distinct` to get only uniq projects

```
Project.joins(:receipts).distinct.where(receipts: { id: [1, 2, 3] })
```